# Determinant of a Special Symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $A$ is a symmatric matrix of odd order with integer entries and the diagonal entries $0$
then $A$ has determinant value even.

I can prove the result if I can show that the eigenvalues of $A$ are integers,but I am unable to do that.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note: $\textrm{eig} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} = \{2.732\ldots, -2, -0.732\ldots\}$.

Comment: it is enough to have the diagonal entries even

Comment: Related to but not duplicate of [What is the determinant of a symmetric n×n matrix with all diagonals be 0 and all others are non-negative integers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/655704/1551)

Comment: @user1551 An approach : A is congruent modulo 2 to a skew-symmetric matrix and an antisymmetric matrix of odd size has a zero determinant.

Comment: What is your argument if the eigenvalues are integers?  (The eigenvalues of an integer matrix are definitely *algebraic* integers, so perhaps the argument can be generalized...)

Comment: @user1551 Have you seen my comment/answer ?

Comment: @Edwin Yes, of course. It's a nice answer. I have already upvoted it, but the bounty period and/or the grace period are not over yet. ^_^

Comment: @user1551 Haha, it's not really for the bounty just no feedback so perhaps its something you do not like..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As suggested by @Grigory M I post this as an answer :

> A is congruent modulo 2 to a skew-symmetric matrix and an antisymmetric matrix of odd size has a zero determinant.

Comment: Very nice!  Note (if anyone else was confused by this) that if a matrix is antisymmetric "mod 2" that does not imply it has determinant zero mod 2 (for obvious reasons).  We must use the fact that the resulting matrix is actually antisymmetric over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 8):

*Hint.* $\det(A)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^na_{i\sigma(i)}$. Partition $S_n$ into three mutually disjoint subsets. The first subset contains those permutations that have some fixed points. The permutations in the second subset are inverses of the permutations in the third one.

Comment: Minor typo: you forgot the term for the sign of the permutation.

Comment: @Goos Ha ha, of course, you are right. It's now fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on user1551's hint, using the formula
$$
\det A = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} {\operatorname{sgn} \sigma} \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i, \sigma(i)}
$$

- For any permutation $\sigma \in S_n$, the inverse permutation $\sigma^{-1}$ has the same sign as $\sigma$.
  Furthermore, since the matrix is symmetric, we can conclude that $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ each contribute the same value to the determinant, **if they are distinct**.
- Permutations such that $\sigma = \sigma^{-1}$ are a product of disjoint transpositions.  Since $n$ is odd, what can we conclude about the contribution of such permutations to the determinant?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and with characteristic $2$. If $A\in M_{2k+1}(R)$ is symmetric or skew-symmetric with $0$ diagonal, then $\det(A)=0$. I gave a sketch of a proof in [Odd-dimensional skew-symmetric matrix is singular, even in a field of characteristic 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795160/odd-dimensional-skew-symmetric-matrix-is-singular-even-in-a-field-of-characteri/795212#795212). Curiously user1551 gave also an answer. Note that we may discuss about the definition of a skew-symmetric matrix in characteristic $2$ ; the notion has not any interest if we do not require that the diagonal must be $0$. Thus it is convenient to add this condition in the definition.

Thus assume that $R$ is any commutative ring with unity (with any characteristic) and$A=[a_{i,j}]\in M_{2k+1}(R)$ with $a_{i,j}=-a_{j,i},a_{i,i}=0$. We work in the ring of polynomials $\mathbb{Z}[(a_{i,j})_{i,j}]$ in the indeterminates $(a_{i,j})$. This ring has no zero-divisors, is factorial and its characteristic is $0$. Clearly $\det(A)\in\mathbb{Z}[(a_{i,j})_{i,j}]$ is $0$ (FORMALLY $0$). The determinant that we consider is an evaluation in $R$ and, consequently, is $0$.

Note that $\mathbb{Z}[(a_{i,j})_{i,j}]$ is also an integrally closed ring. This is a key to show that, if $A\in M_{2k}(R)$, then  $\det(A)$ is the square of an element of $R$.